# How can I fixed DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated error

Tags: nlp, extract, stanford-nlp, word2vec, summarization

While working with Word2Vec, I got an error like this :

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `__getitem__` (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.**getitem**() instead).
This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
sentences=sent_tokenize(text)
sentences
nltk.download('stopwords')
sentences_clean=[re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',sentence.lower()) for sentence in sentences] #noktalama kaldır , küçült 
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
sentence_tokens=[[words for words in sentence.split(' ') if words not in stop_words] for sentence in sentences_clean] #stop_words'leri kaldır.
sentence_tokens
#SÖZCÜK YERLEŞTİRME
w2v=Word2Vec(sentence_tokens,size=1,min_count=1,iter=1000)
sentence_embeddings=[[w2v[word][0] for word in words] for words in sentence_tokens]
max_len=max([len(tokens) for tokens in sentence_tokens]) #Bir cümlenin max uzunluğunu hesaplama
sentence_embeddings=[np.pad(embedding,(0,max_len-len(embedding)),'constant') for embedding in sentence_embeddings] #Padding işlemi.Bütün cümleleri aynı boyuta getirebilmke için yaplır
#print(sentence_embeddings) #Kelimelerin vektör uzayındaki halleri bulunur
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should provide in your question the full error message, with call stack ("traceback") info, to help highlight exactly which line of code has triggered the error.

But, I believe your error is being triggered by the part of your code that uses `w2v[word]`.

A `DeprecationWarning` typically means your usage is no-longer-recommended because of changes in the library code's design. While the 'deprecation' warning occurs, the code likely still works, but may stop working in a later release.

In the case of your code, in the version of Gensim you're using, it's no-longer-recommended to access word-vectors by direct indexed-access (`[…]`-subscripting) on the `Word2Vec` model object itself. Instead, those word-vectors are now collected in a subsidiary object, of type `KeyedVectors`, that's kept in the `Word2Vec` object's `.wv` property.

So, replacing `w2v[word]` with `w2v.wv[word]` should avoid the warning. (And, is likely necessary for the code to work at all, starting in `gensim-4.0.0` & higher versions.)

Comment: I solved the problem with your answer. Thank you :) :)